# javascript to update price of 4 dropdown & 2 check box button.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The above code is not working the way I want. The user should be able to select one option from each drop down menu & as soon as he selects a option price should be updated (at this point an alert box will do). User should be able to re-select any drop down menu if he/she wants and proper calculations needs to be done accordingly.

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Title</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css">         

        <script type="text/javascript">    
            function dropdown() {   
                var drp = document.getElementById("numberlist");  
                var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");  
                optn.text="3";  
                optn.value="3";  
                drp.add(optn);  
                }   

            function Add() {
                var e = document.getElementById('numberlist');
                var txt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                var txt_int = parseInt(txt);
                var final_txt = show(txt_int);
                //return final_txt;

                //alert(txt_int);
            }   


            function show(price) {  

                if(document.my_form.but1.checked == true) {
                    //alert("Box1 is checked");
                    price += 10;
                    } 

                else if(document.my_form.but2.checked == true) {
                    //alert("Box 2 is checked");
                    price += 15;
                    }

                //return price;
                alert(price);   
            }

        </script>  
    </head>   
    <body onload="dropdown();"> 

    <form name="my_form">
        <select id="numberlist" onchange="Add()"> 
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>36</option>
        </select> 

         <select id="numberlist" onchange="Add()"> 
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>36</option>
        </select> 

        <select id="numberlist" onchange="Add()"> 
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>36</option>
        </select> 

        <select id="numberlist" onchange="Add()"> 
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>36</option>
        </select> 

        <br /> <p>

        <input type="checkbox" name=but1 onchange="show()"> Gift Wrap $10 <br /> 
        <input type="checkbox" name=but2 onchange="show()"> Express Shipping $15<br /> <p>

    </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we provide solution using jQuery? very short code in comparison to normal javascript.

Comment: Thank you apul for your code. I jQuery solution is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues I see right of the bat.

Your select elements all have the same id attribute.  This is a definite no-no. The use of document.getElementById() will only return one element.

If you want to get a handle on all of the select fields in your Add() and dropdown() functions, you should use the name attribute instead of the id attribute and query for these elements with  document.getElementsByName(nameValue).  This will return an array of all of your select elements which you would want to iterate over with a for loop.

The other issue is with your show() function.  You have the parameter "price" defined in the function, buy you are not calling the function with a "price" argument. You can define a global price variable that will be accessible by all the functions with the window.

```js
//Define a global price variable that will be visible to every function
var price;

//Add extra option to 'numberlist' select elements
function initDropdownOptions() {
  //Grab all select elements by their name attribute
  var selectElements = document.getElementsByName("numberlist");

  //Initialize/Define for loop conditions variables
  var numberOfDropdowns = selectElements.length;
  var i;

  //Define a reusable temp option variable to be reused
  var optn;

  //Iterate over select elements
  for( i = 0; i < numberOfDropdowns; i++ ){
    //Create a new option element and save it to the optn variable
    optn = document.createElement("OPTION");

    //Set the text of the option
    optn.text="3";

    //Set the value of the option
    optn.value="3";

    //Add the option to the ith select element
    selectElements[i].add( optn );  
  }
}   

function calculatePrice() {
  //Grab all select elements by their name attribute
  var selectElements = document.getElementsByName("numberlist");

  //Initilize/Define for loop conditions variables
  var i;
  var numberOfDropdowns = selectElements.length;
  

  //Define a temp holder for the select values
  var tmpSelectValue;

  //Initialize the global price variable to 0
  price = 0;

  for( i = 0; i < numberOfDropdowns; i++ ){
    //Extract the value from the select element
    tmpSelectValue = selectElements[i].options[ selectElements[i].selectedIndex ].value
    
    //Parse the tmpSelectValue into a number and add it to the global price
    price += parseFloat( tmpSelectValue );
  }

  //Add additional Charges if they are applicable
  var giftWrapChecked   = (document.my_form.but1.checked == true);
  var expressShippingChecked  = (document.my_form.but2.checked == true);
  
  if( giftWrapChecked ) {
    //Add aditional 10$
    price += 10;
  } 

  if( expressShippingChecked ) {
    //Add additional 15$
    price += 15;
  }

  //Output the price to the currentPrice div
  document.getElementById("currentPrice").innerHTML = price;

}
```

```html
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Title</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css">         
    </head>   
    <body onload="initDropdownOptions();"> 

    <form name="my_form">

        <select name="numberlist" onchange="calculatePrice()"> 
            <option value='0'>Select</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
            <option value='24'>24</option>
            <option value='36'>36</option>
        </select> 

         <select name="numberlist" onchange="calculatePrice()"> 
            <option value='0'>Select</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
            <option value='24'>24</option>
            <option value='36'>36</option>
        </select> 

        <select name="numberlist" onchange="calculatePrice()"> 
            <option value='0'>Select</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
            <option value='24'>24</option>
            <option value='36'>36</option>
        </select> 

        <select name="numberlist" onchange="calculatePrice()"> 
            <option value='0'>Select</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
            <option value='24'>24</option>
            <option value='36'>36</option>
        </select> 

        <br /> 
      
       <p>
  <input type="checkbox" name=but1 onchange="calculatePrice()"> Gift Wrap $10 <br /> 
         <input type="checkbox" name=but2 onchange="calculatePrice()"> Express Shipping $15<br />
       <p>
          
        <div id='currentPrice'></div>

    </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using jQuery:

Try it:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form name="my_form">
  <select id="numberlist1" class="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
  </select>
  <select id="numberlist2" class="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
  </select>
  <select id="numberlist3" class="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
  </select>
  <select id="numberlist4" class="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="but1" value="10" />
    Gift Wrap $10 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="but2" value="15" />
    Express Shipping $15<br />
  <p>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('input:checkbox, select.dropdown').change(function(){

var price = 0;
$('input:checkbox, select.dropdown').each(function(){
// Your Show function
if($(this).is('input:checkbox') )
{
if($(this).is(':checked'))
    price += parseInt($(this).val());
}
else
price += parseInt($(this).val());


});

alert(price);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```